# How to aggregate a dataframe then transpose it with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to achieve this kind of transformation with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

[image]

I made this code but unfortunately it doesn't give the result I'm searching for.

#### CODE :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=';')

df = df.count().reset_index().T.reset_index()

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]

df
```

#### RESULT :

[image]

Do you have any proposition ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create columns for test `nonOK` and then use named aggregatoin for count, sum column `Values` and for count `True`s values use `sum` again, last sum both columns:

```
df = (df.assign(NumberOfTest1 = df['Test one'].eq('nonOK'),
                NumberOfTest2 = df['Test two'].eq('nonOK'))
        .groupby('Category', as_index=False)
        .agg(NumberOfID = ('ID','size'),
             Values = ('Values','sum'),
             NumberOfTest1 = ('NumberOfTest1','sum'),
             NumberOfTest2 = ('NumberOfTest2','sum'))
        .assign(TotalTest = lambda x: x['NumberOfTest1'] + x['NumberOfTest2']))
```

Comment: First, I added a missing `)` in your code and then a `.reset_index()` to get the result I'm looking for. And it worked ! Thank you so much @jezrael

Comment: @wasp-96b - Or use `.groupby('Category', as_index=False)` ;)

Comment: Perfect, it's even better like that. I added `as_index=False` in the groupby clause. Don't forget to add the missing `)` in the end of your code. Thank you again man ;)